# PJAX + jQuery modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I'm building this web page and I want the news to appear in jquery.modal, but with sharing functionality, that means with the URL. I found PJAX for the solution and then I wanted to put the link in URL and show the content in the modal window. 
After days of googling I stumbled on this, and if you click on the page it opens in modal, but shows the URL, but I can't find how it works. Here is the link: http://rigaspots.blogspot.com/

Here is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.modal.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var direction = "right";
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').pjax({
container: '.modal'
});

$('.modal').on('pjax:start', function() {
  $(this).addClass('loading')
})

$('.modal').on('pjax:end', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('loading')
})


});


</script>

<style> 

#main {
  font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;   
  width:30%;  
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.20s linear;
}

#main.loading {
   opacity: 0.5;
}   
h2 {margin-left:200px;}
   ul{padding-left:15px; list-style:none;}
</style> 

</head>
<body>
<p ><strong style='color:green'> 2012-10-25 16:52:13</strong> (Time should only change on     refresh!)</p><div id="main">
<h1>PJAX using PHP</h1>

<ul class='header'>
  <li><a href='trex.php' data-pjax='modal' rel="modal:open">Tyrannosaurus</a></li>
  <li><a href='kong.php' data-pjax='modal' rel="modal:open" >King Kong</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

You can see it here: http://supervalters.mplab.lv/source/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the PJAX library a bit more, it should give some more clarity. Essentially though, PJAX just makes and AJAX request and then parses the returned HTML to replace only the content belonging to that container. https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax